# GTK+/Cairo - drawing to a temporary layer?

Tags: graphics, drawing, drag, gtk, cairo

I'm drawing nodes on to a window, and when you click them I want it select the node and color it a different colour. 
And then it might go off and do something else, and I want it to return the original color.

Is there a way of drawing on to an overlapping layer, and then just undisplay that layer?

Ie, rather than having to go through and redraw everything again.

Similarly - if I'm want a 'drag to draw line', how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try with something like [goocanvas](http://live.gnome.org/GooCanvas) widgets.